Add linked geometry node asset via script
How can I add a geometry node, that I have marked as an asset, to another Blender file via a script? And also add it directly to the active object?
import bpy

filepath = "C:\\WORKSPACE\\Library\\GeometryNodes.blend"

link = True

with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=True) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.objects = [name for name in data_from.objects if name.startswith("GeometryNode_HouseBuild1")]
    modifier=bpy.context.object.modifiers.new("GeometryNode", "NODES")
    modifier.node_group = bpy.data.node_groups['GeometryNode_HouseBuild1']

The script should load the library with the geometry node and add a modifier with the geometry node linked to the active object (curve). But it does not seem to access the library, because an error appears saying that it could not find the geometry node

A function that add a GN modifier to a mesh object and assign a specific node from a blend file.
import bpy
from os.path import join as os_path_join

def add_gn_modifier_with(obj, file_path, node_name, method="LINK"):
    if hasattr(obj, "type"):
        if obj.type != "MESH":
            print("MESH object only")
            return
    else:
        print("Invalid object")
        return

    if file_path == bpy.data.filepath:
        print("Not allow load library from current file")
        # Don't append current file, It will crash blender even the code inside the try:
        return

    inner_path = "NodeTree"
    node_groups = bpy.data.node_groups

    def wm_append(link=True):
        try:
            bpy.ops.wm.append(
                filepath=os_path_join(file_path, inner_path, node_name),
                directory=os_path_join(file_path, inner_path),
                filename=node_name,
                link=link)
        except Exception as ex:
            # file_path or node_name may wrong
            print(str(ex))
            return False
        return True

    if method == "LINK":
        name_tuple = node_name, file_path

        if name_tuple in node_groups:
            pass
            # Already Linked
        else:
            if not wm_append(link=True):
                return

        if name_tuple in node_groups:
            node = node_groups[name_tuple]
        else:
            print("node group not found in the file_path")
            return

    elif method == "APPEND":
        if node_name in node_groups:
            old_node_groups = set(node_groups)

            if not wm_append(link=False):
                return

            try:
                node = next(ob  for ob in node_groups  if ob not in old_node_groups)
            except:
                print("node group not found in the file_path")
                return
        else:
            if not wm_append(link=False):
                return

            if node_name in node_groups:
                node = node_groups[node_name]
            else:
                print("node group not found in the file_path")
                return

    elif method == "REUSE":
        print("Unsupport method")
        return
    else:
        print("Unsupport method")
        return

    if node.type != "GEOMETRY":
        node_groups.remove(node)
        print("Wrong Node Type")
        # you may want to check if the node marked as asset
        return

    md = obj.modifiers.new(node_name, "NODES")
    md.node_group = node

